# how can read() return -1 value in this code? when client send data to server, server read properly.after reading, read() method not return -1 value

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to use `read()` method in socket programming.

```
 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
                out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8");

                while ((s = in.read()) != -1) {
                    char c = (char) s;
                    str = str + c;
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
                System.out.println("+++++");
```

In this code when client sends data to server as I:987. server reads it properly. after reading, it is waiting more inputs. but I want to break loop after reading data. I don't want to use `println()` method. how can `(s = in.read())` return -1.

Comment: `if (<client determines all data has been read>) { break; }`

Comment: What exactly is your question ? The code you posted does what you said in title. Terminates when you read all data from the input. Use more words please.

Comment: I assume your blocking on the read.  You can either test for the end of the data after a successful read, interrupt the reader thread, or switch to NIO, which has a non-blocking mode.  socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

Comment: In this code when client send data to server as I:987. server read it properly. after reading, it is waiting more inputs. but i want to break loop after reading data. I don't want to use println() method. how can (s = in.read()) return -1.

Comment: If the other end of the socket closes the connection, read will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                s = in.read();
                while (in.ready()) { // receiving data from client
                    s = in.read();
                    char c = (char) s;
                    str = str + c;
                }
```

by using in.ready() method I solved my problem.
Thanks to all.